# Creating a sublist inside a Trello list

Tags: trello, trello-lists

Is it posible to make a sublist inside a Trello list? (It would be *very* useful.)

Comment: Do you mean adding a checklist to a card, or a sublist inside a checklist?

Comment: Can you explain use cases where it would be useful? Maybe it can be accomplished differently in Trello.

Answer (score 12):

You can create a sublist in a list. Just type **three times space then create an element of a list like you would normally do**.

[image: how it looks]

Comment: Even though I suspect the OP was asking about Trello checklists, this post was the top result when I was searching for how to do it in Trello markdown comments, so +1 to this answer.

Answer (score 9):

It's not possible.

You can, instead, create several checklists, and you'll have two levels:

- First level: a 'list' of checklists
- Second level: list in each checklist, as usual

Advantages:

- When all tasks of second level are done, then the first level is shown as done.

Disadvantages:

- You can't have more sub levels.
- You can't mark as done a checklist without marking as done all items in its list.

[image: Minimum working example of an alternative of doing sub lists in lists]

Answer (score 2):

No.

> A list is collection of vertically-arranged cards. They may represent a collection of ideas, things to remember, or different stages of a workflow.

[Source](http://help.trello.com/article/744-adding-lists-to-a-board).

Answer (score 2):

Sort of, if you ignore the semantics for a minute.

1. Create a 'summary' board to summarize your different projects (each
   card = a project)
2. Create a seperate board for each of those projects (each card = a
   task)
3. Copy the hyperlink for each project board [click on the board name
   in the top left corner, then click share, then 'CTRL C' the
   hyperlink...], then go back to the 'summary' board and paste it into
   either the description or the 'activities' box of the relavent card
   for that project
4. you can do this ad-infinitum to create (hyperlinked) boards inside
   boards inside boards...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Nests for Trello. It is a Chrome extension. It allows you to create a board as a card. Based on your structure,

1. The "summary board" will be the main board.
2. Each project will be a list within the "summary board"
3. and within the list you can add a board for that project (which will show up as a card). but when you click on it, it will bring you to a new board (for that specific project).

Comment: This answer would be much more useful with a link to the extension. Also, if you have a vested interest in what you're recommending you must disclose it. Please see the [help/behavior].

Comment: Link to the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nests-for-trello/eibnacdidooamhebiehhlafljlipplmd

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about text formatting, it is possible (however it's a bit tedious).

Just start your list with `-` (make sure it is separated from the rest of the text with a new line), and then on the next item add a `>` to give you an indentation. This will separate the next item into a sub-list of the previous list. So, something like this:

```
- first item in list
> - first item in sublist
> - second item in sublist
> - ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The "share" and hyperlink suggestion worked for me with an addition.

- I created a "Committee Top Level" checklist card
- I entered each committee as a hyperlink checklist card as described earlier
- The difference is I entered the "Committee Top Level" hyperlink in each of committee's description box.
  This allows me to bounce down to a committee and bounce right back to where I was. You could put additional hyperlinks in the descriptions if you frequently bounce elsewhere. Really cleaned up my view as I now keep the actual committee card at the bottom of my card list.